# What causes the layout problems of my Datatable?

Tags: datatables, yadcf

I am building an app in which I want use Datatables with various plugins and I observed some weird layout-problems. So I tried to build a repro. And as worked on that, new problems occurred and I even failed to sort these out.
So here I am with the current state of my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mbaas/5ehk8nmn/)

I have no idea what's causing these issues. I have attached a bit of code (because  it is required, but with reduced data).  The issues I'm currently struggling with:

- `yadcf`-Filters incomplete...
- footer-defects: pagelength-selector missing, paging-controls missing. Whenever I saw that in the past, there were some JS-Errors (usually with my code), but this time I'm not seeing anything in the console.

**Update1**: I've now managed to get rid of column1-resizing. The `range_number_slider`for yadcf does not render correctly - am I missing a resource?? 
Updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mbaas/5ehk8nmn/).

```
    $(function() {
      dtObj = $("#dataset").DataTable({
        "buttons": [{
          "columns": ":gt(1)",
          "extend": "colvis",
          "text": "Series"
        }],
        "scrollX": true,
        "dom": "Bfrtip",
        "lengthMenu": [
          [10, 25, 50, -1],
          ["10 rows", "25 rows", "50 rows", "Show all"]
        ],
        "columns": [{
          "data": "_include",
          "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
            var res = '';
            if (row._include) {
                                res='<span onclick="toggleRecord(' + row._id + ')"><i class="fal fa-eye"></i></span>';
                            } else {
                                res='<span onclick="toggleRecord(' + row._id + ')"><i class="fal fa-eye-slash"></i></span>';
                }
            return res;


          },
          "title": "Include",
          "visible": true,
          "width": "2em;"
        }, {
          "data": "_id",
          "title": "ID",
          "visible": false
        }, {
          "className": "text-right",
          "data": "Car",
          "title": "Car",
          "visible": false,
          "width": "80px"
        }, {
          "data": "Eyes",
          "title": "Eyes",
          "visible": false,
          "width": "80px"
        }, {
          "className": "text-right",
          "data": "Family",
          "title": "Family",
          "visible": false,
          "width": "80px"
        }, {
          "data": "Hand",
          "title": "Hand",
          "visible": true,
          "width": "80px"
        }, {
          "className": "text-right",
          "data": "HealthCare",
          "title": "HealthCare",
          "visible": false,
          "width": "80px"
        }, {
          "className": "text-right",
          "data": "Height",
          "title": "Height",
          "visible": true,
          "width": "80px"
        }, {
          "data": "Major",
          "title": "Major",
          "visible": true,
          "width": "80px"
        }, {
          "className": "text-right",
          "data": "Marriage",
          "title": "Marriage",
          "visible": false,
          "width": "80px"
        }, {
          "data": "Party",
          "title": "Party",
          "visible": false,
          "width": "80px"
        }, {
          "className": "text-right",
          "data": "Pot",
          "title": "Pot",
          "visible": false,
          "width": "80px"
        }, {
          "data": "Sex",
          "title": "Sex",
          "visible": false,
          "width": "80px"
        }, {
          "className": "text-right",
          "data": "ShoeSize",
          "title": "ShoeSize",
          "visible": false,
          "width": "80px"
        }, {
          "data": "State",
          "title": "State",
          "visible": true,
          "width": "80px"
        }, {
          "className": "text-right",
          "data": "Student",
          "title": "Student",
          "visible": false,
          "width": "80px"
        }, {
          "className": "text-right",
          "data": "Weight",
          "title": "Weight",
          "visible": false,
          "width": "80px"
        }],
        "createdRow": function(row, data, dataIndex) {
          row.id = 'r' + data._id;
          if (!data._include) {
            $(row).children(":gt(2)").addClass('excludeRow');
          }
        },
        "data": [{
          "Car": 1,
          "Eyes": "Blue",
          "Family": 3,
          "Hand": "R",
          "HealthCare": 2,
          "Height": 72,
          "Major": "FIN",
          "Marriage": 5,
          "Party": "R",
          "Pot": 4,
          "Sex": "M",
          "ShoeSize": 11.5,
          "State": "PA",
          "Student": 1,
          "Weight": 220,
          "_id": 1,
          "_include": true
        }, {
          "Car": 1,
          "Eyes": "Brown",
          "Family": 4,
          "Hand": "R",
          "HealthCare": 1,
          "Height": 62,
          "Major": "ACC",
          "Marriage": 1,
          "Party": "D",
          "Pot": 5,
          "Sex": "F",
          "ShoeSize": 9,
          "State": "PA",
          "Student": 2,
          "Weight": 140,
          "_id": 2,
          "_include": true
        }, {
          "Car": 0,
          "Eyes": "Blue",
          "Family": 0,
          "Hand": "R",
          "HealthCare": 3,
          "Height": 69,
          "Major": "FIN",
          "Marriage": 1,
          "Party": "D",
          "Pot": 4,
          "Sex": "M",
          "ShoeSize": 11,
          "State": "MD",
          "Student": 3,
          "Weight": 195,
          "_id": 3,
          "_include": true
        }, {
          "Car": 1,
          "Eyes": "Blue",
          "Family": 1,
          "Hand": "R",
          "HealthCare": 2,
          "Height": 69,
          "Major": "OIM",
          "Marriage": 1,
          "Party": "D",
          "Pot": 3,
          "Sex": "M",
          "ShoeSize": 9.5,
          "State": "PA",
          "Student": 4,
          "Weight": 190,
          "_id": 4,
          "_include": true
        }, {
          "Car": 1,
          "Eyes": "Brown",
          "Family": 1,
          "Hand": "L",
          "HealthCare": 2,
          "Height": 70,
          "Major": "BA",
          "Marriage": 4,
          "Party": "R",
          "Pot": 5,
          "Sex": "M",
          "ShoeSize": 10.5,
          "State": "CT",
          "Student": 5,
          "Weight": 150,
          "_id": 5,
          "_include": true
        }, {
          "Car": 1,
          "Eyes": "Brown",
          "Family": 2,
          "Hand": "R",
          "HealthCare": 4,
          "Height": 66,
          "Major": "ACC",
          "Marriage": 2,
          "Party": "R",
          "Pot": 3,
          "Sex": "M",
          "ShoeSize": 8.25,
          "State": "NJ",
          "Student": 6,
          "Weight": 125,
          "_id": 6,
          "_include": true
        }, {
          "Car": 0,
          "Eyes": "Brown",
          "Family": 1,
          "Hand": "R",
          "HealthCare": 2,
          "Height": 67,
          "Major": "BA",
          "Marriage": 2,
          "Party": "D",
          "Pot": 4,
          "Sex": "M",
          "ShoeSize": 9,
          "State": "NY",
          "Student": 7,
          "Weight": 155,
          "_id": 7,
          "_include": true
        }, {
          "Car": 1,
          "Eyes": "Green",
          "Family": 2,
          "Hand": "L",
          "HealthCare": 1,
          "Height": 72,
          "Major": "OIM",
          "Marriage": 2,
          "Party": "I",
          "Pot": 4,
          "Sex": "M",
          "ShoeSize": 13,
          "State": "PA",
          "Student": 8,
          "Weight": 260,
          "_id": 8,
          "_include": true
        }, {
          "Car": 1,
          "Eyes": "Blue",
          "Family": 2,
          "Hand": "R",
          "HealthCare": 3,
          "Height": 72,
          "Major": "BA",
          "Marriage": 2,
          "Party": "R",
          "Pot": 4,
          "Sex": "M",
          "ShoeSize": 10.5,
          "State": "NY",
          "Student": 9,
          "Weight": 155,
          "_id": 9,
          "_include": true
        }, {
          "Car": 1,
          "Eyes": "Brown",
          "Family": 2,
          "Hand": "R",
          "HealthCare": 3,
          "Height": 71,
          "Major": "ACC",
          "Marriage": 2,
          "Party": "D",
          "Pot": 4,
          "Sex": "M",
          "ShoeSize": 12,
          "State": "CT",
          "Student": 10,
          "Weight": 180,
          "_id": 10,
          "_include": true
        }, {
          "Car": 1,
          "Eyes": "Blue",
          "Family": 1,
          "Hand": "R",
          "HealthCare": 3,
          "Height": 71,
          "Major": "BA",
          "Marriage": 4,
          "Party": "R",
          "Pot": 2,
          "Sex": "M",
          "ShoeSize": 11,
          "State": "MD",
          "Student": 11,
          "Weight": 160,
          "_id": 11,
          "_include": true
        }]
      });
      yadcf.init($("#dataset").DataTable(), [{
        "column_number": 0,
        "filter_type": "range_number_slider"
      }, {
        "column_number": 1,
        "filter_type": "multi_select",
        "select_type": "chosen"
      }, {
        "column_number": 2,
        "filter_type": "range_number_slider"
      }, {
        "column_number": 3,
        "filter_type": "multi_select",
        "select_type": "chosen"
      }, {
        "column_number": 4,
        "filter_type": "range_number_slider"
      }, {
        "column_number": 5,
        "filter_type": "range_number_slider"
      }, {
        "column_number": 6,
        "filter_type": "multi_select",
        "select_type": "chosen"
      }, {
        "column_number": 7,
        "filter_type": "range_number_slider"
      }, {
        "column_number": 8,
        "filter_type": "multi_select",
        "select_type": "chosen"
      }, {
        "column_number": 9,
        "filter_type": "range_number_slider"
      }, {
        "column_number": 10,
        "filter_type": "multi_select",
        "select_type": "chosen"
      }, {
        "column_number": 11,
        "filter_type": "range_number_slider"
      }, {
        "column_number": 12,
        "filter_type": "multi_select",
        "select_type": "chosen"
      }, {
        "column_number": 13,
        "filter_type": "range_number_slider"
      }, {
        "column_number": 14,
        "filter_type": "range_number_slider"
      }]);
    });

  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/mbaas/fbo0L88v/
```

Comment: jsfiddle not really working... also what is the exact issue with yadcf

Comment: Sorry - fixed (colvis was missing). The yadcf-issue that I hope to post a sample for ultimately is that the first visible filter spans 2 columns. As soon as I force redraw of the table (by making another columns visible), that problems goes away. (Sample screenshot: https://www.screencast.com/t/iTNSML3b )

Comment: if you will provide a simple test page with steps to reproduce 1)look at filter "Y", press button "ShowX" to show column "X", "how come after clicking on "ShowX" filter "Y" changed its size .... etc... then It will be possible to try and help (for me at least)

Comment: That's what I tried to do when desaster struck ;-) I will continue research...

Comment: Daniel: I made some progress...but can't see why `range_number_slider`does not render correctly...

Comment: Fixed most problems. Will come back with one remaining issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issues with the Datatable (most notable I did not load the appropriate .css to support Bootstrap for the addons), I then had an issue with the pagelength-control not being wide enough to fully show the text for the "All"-Selection - that required some changes to the CSS which Allan will include in his downloads.
Just in case anyone else hits this:

```
  div.dataTables_wrapper div.dataTables_length select {
    width: auto;
  }
```

Then I had an issue with vertical alignment of the controls surrounding the table - that needed a slightly more evolved `dom`-setting than I had:

```
"<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-6'B><'col-sm-12 col-md-6'f>>" + 
"<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" + 
"<'row'<'col-sm-12'i>>" + 
"<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'l><'col-sm-12 col-md-7'p>>"
```

This should become significantly easier with one the next releases...

Even after sorting all that out, the yadcf-issue remained - but that seems to be a real bug, so I posted an [issue](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues/468) on GitHub.